# Ajax response - wrong values on client side

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

The server recieves and sends correct data through the endpoints, yet on the client-side some data are changed.

The network tab in dev-console - the 15th and 18th object's value.value are strings. The 15th is "false" and the 18th is "true"

[image: The network tab in dev-console - the 15th and 18th object's value.value are strings. The 15th is "false" and the 18th is "true"]

Console.logging the response from the server I get wrong values for specifically these keys - Booleans which are false in this case

[image: Console.logging the response from the server I get wrong values for specifically these keys - Booleans which are false in this case]

**The utility request function I use, it doesn't change the response :**

```
export let request = (method,url,params,headers = {}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method || "GET", url);
        if (headers) {
            Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {

                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));

            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(params);
    });
};
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I suspect the code that runs when the request is resolved is modifying the objects.

Comment: hmm, yes you are right...
it seems that when resolving it changes the values...